# Circle inscribed in triangle problem

Tags: mathematics, geometry, triangle

You need to find the angle BEC knowing that the side BC is tangent to the circumference.

[image: Graphic]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Is this an original puzzle or copied? If it is copied, could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: This is a puzzle that I created with a friend. To the best of my knowledge it is the original puzzle.

Comment: The circle is meant to be tangential to all three lines around it, right? It looks not-quite-tangential to the x-axis, but I suppose that's just a drawing artefact. Also, what is F?

Comment: F doesn't mean anything. I forgot to take it off. The three lines are tangential to the circle.

Comment: Here's a redraw with things constructed so that everything that's supposed to be tangent is actually tangent: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llDem.png Feel free to edit this into your post if you want.

Comment: This question should not be closed.it is a mathematical puzzle. I personally think it fits the criteria mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's draw a few more points and line segments:

[image: annotated diagram with P,Q,R]

---

By looking at the side lengths,

> triangles $CER$ and $CEP$ are congruent, and so are triangles $BER$ and $BEQ$.

Therefore, angle $BEC$ is

> angle $BER$ (equals angle $BEQ$) plus angle $CER$ (equals angle $CEP$), which is exactly half of angle $PEQ$ (the sum of all four mentioned angles).

By quadrilateral $APEQ$, the angle $PEQ$ is $180-22=158$ degrees,

> so the angle $BEC$ is half of this which is $79$ degrees.

---

**Commentary**

Originally (see revision history of this answer), I did a sort of meta solution: the OP assumes that the value of the angle $BEC$ does not depend on the exact positions of $B$ and $C$, only on the fact that the line $BC$ is tangential to the circle. Therefore, by rotating this tangent line to its extreme possible positions, we can get an answer. But this doesn't *prove* that the angle is invariant as $BC$ rotates: I just *assumed* it by exploiting the wording of the question.

My earlier attempts had involved a lot of messing around with angles, but not using any lengths. I realised that I was using the right angles at $EPC$, $EQB$, $CER$, $BER$, but never using the fact that the radii $EP$, $EQ$, $ER$ are of equal lengths. Somehow this fact has got to be used, otherwise it's useless information and the circle could be an ellipse with perpendicular tangent lines. Then I figured out how to use it and the answer became clear.

Comment: How would you prove that the angle BEC stays constant as you move it?

Comment: @user78580 I'm not sure about that, but your question implies it :-) (Kind of cheating, I know - I'm trying to figure out how to prove it.)

Comment: @user78580 Aha, got it. Done.

Comment: Here's a redraw, with everything properly constructed and to scale, corresponding to the redraw of the question I commented: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAMFo.png